# How to display nested object json with forEach method

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to build an app using the free rawg api.
I have this json

```
results: 
added_by_status: {yet: 463, owned: 3266, beaten: 428, toplay: 2237, dropped: 101, …}
background_image: "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/26d/26d4437715bee60138dab4a7c8c59c92.jpg"
clip: {clip: "https://media.rawg.io/media/stories-640/f78/f789c8011d52e0ffac76b11a88fabee7.mp4", clips: {…}, video: "59pvij73-N0", preview: "https://media.rawg.io/media/stories-previews/fad/fad39fae9b0809ab42ff03586e7204de.jpg"}
dominant_color: "0f0f0f"
esrb_rating: {id: 5, name: "Adults Only", slug: "adults-only", name_en: "Adults Only", name_ru: "Только для взрослых"}
genres: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
id: 41494
metacritic: 68
name: "Cyberpunk 2077"
parent_platforms: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
platforms: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
playtime: 19
rating: 4.12
rating_top: 5
ratings: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
ratings_count: 841
released: "2020-12-10"
reviews_count: 883
```

and my javascript

```
const APIURL = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=50&dates=2020-01-01,2021-12-31&ordering=-added';
        const main = document.querySelector('main');

        async function getGames() {
            let resp = await fetch(APIURL);
            let respData = await resp.json();   

            console.log(respData);

            respData.results.forEach(game => {

            const { background_image, metacritic, name, platforms, platforms: {platform} } = game;
             
            console.log(platforms[0].platform.name);
            
                let gameEl = document.createElement('div');
                gameEl.classList.add('game');
                gameEl.innerHTML = `
            
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url(${background_image})"></div>
            <div id="game-info" class="game-info" >
                <div id="platforms" class="platforms"></div> 
                <h3>${name}</h3>
                <span class="${getRatingClass(metacritic)}">${metacritic}</span>
            </div> `;

                main.appendChild(gameEl)
                
            });
            return respData;
        }
        function getRatingClass(voto) {
            if (voto >= 80) {
                return 'green';
            } else if (voto >= 50) {
                return 'orange';
            } else {
                return 'red';
            }
        }
        getGames();
```

Now everything works but I can't display the nested array "platform" which has "platform", "name", "id" and "slug" inside. Like this:

```
platforms: Array(5)
0:
platform:
id: 4
name: "PC"
slug: "pc"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
1: {platform: {…}}
2: {platform: {…}}
3: {platform: {…}}
4: {platform: {…}}
```

how do i display the platforms in the div with id = "platforms"? Thanks!

Comment: `platform` is an object, not an array.

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: The "JSON" listed in the question does not look like JSON. Also is `respData.results` an object or an array? I can't tell for sure, but from the psuedo-JSON listing it looks like it may be an object. You wouldn't use `.forEach` with an object.

Comment: `platforms.forEach(({platform}) => do stuff with platform.id, platform.name, platform.slug )`

Comment: look here https://www.gdrdesign.it/games_app.html

Comment: @Barmar but inside first forEach?

Comment: I don't think so. `platforms` is an array of objects. Each object has a `platform` property that contains a nested object. That object has `id`, `name`, and `slug` properties.

Comment: It would be easier to tell for sure if you posted the JSON rather than the output of `console.log`

Comment: I did not understand anything but thanks anyway...

Comment: @Barmar i have posted the link...

Comment: @Barmar https://www.gdrdesign.it/games_app.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues, but you inevitably want this:

```js
`<div id="platforms" class="platforms">
  ${platforms.map(({ platform: { name } }) =>
    `<span class="platform">${name || ''}</span>`
  ).join('')}
</div>`
```

1. First, `respData.results` is not an array, make sure it is enclosed in one.
2. Second, just destructure the `platforms` and deal with it later when it comes to mapping.

I modified your object to include the follwoing:

```js
"platforms": [
  { "platform": { "name": "Playstation" } },
  { "platform": { "name": "PC" } }
]
```

### Basic example using local data

```js
const respData = {
  "results": [{
    "added_by_status": {
      "yet": 463,
      "owned": 3266,
      "beaten": 428,
      "toplay": 2237,
      "dropped": 101
    },
    "background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/26d/26d4437715bee60138dab4a7c8c59c92.jpg",
    "clip": {
      "clip": "https://media.rawg.io/media/stories-640/f78/f789c8011d52e0ffac76b11a88fabee7.mp4",
      "clips": {},
      "video": "59pvij73-N0",
      "preview": "https://media.rawg.io/media/stories-previews/fad/fad39fae9b0809ab42ff03586e7204de.jpg"
    },
    "dominant_color": "0f0f0f",
    "esrb_rating": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Adults Only",
      "slug": "adults-only",
      "name_en": "Adults Only",
      "name_ru": "Только для взрослых"
    },
    "genres": [{}, {}, {}],
    "id": 41494,
    "metacritic": 68,
    "name": "Cyberpunk 2077",
    "parent_platforms": [{}, {}, {}],
    "platforms": [{ "platform": { "name": "Playstation" } }, { "platform": { "name": "PC" } }],
    "playtime": 19,
    "rating": 4.12,
    "rating_top": 5,
    "ratings": [{}, {}, {}, {}],
    "ratings_count": 841,
    "released": "2020-12-10",
    "reviews_count": 883
  }]
}

const main = document.querySelector('main');

respData.results.forEach(game => {
  const {
    background_image,
    metacritic,
    name,
    platforms
  } = game;

  let gameEl = document.createElement('div');
  gameEl.classList.add('game');
  gameEl.innerHTML = `     
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(${background_image})"></div>
    <div id="game-info" class="game-info" >
        <div id="platforms" class="platforms">
          ${platforms.map(({ platform: { name } }) =>
            `<span class="platform">${name || ''}</span>`
          ).join('')}
        </div> 
        <h3>${name}</h3>
        <span class="${getRatingClass(metacritic)}">${metacritic}</span>
    </div>
  `;
  main.appendChild(gameEl)
});

function getRatingClass(voto) {
  if      (voto >= 80) return 'green';
  else if (voto >= 50) return 'orange';
  else                 return 'red';
}
```

```css
.platforms {
  display: flex;
}

.platform {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

### Full example using API call

```js
const main = () => {
  const mainEl = document.querySelector('main');
  fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=50&dates=2020-01-01,2021-12-31&ordering=-added')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(respData => render(respData.results, mainEl));
};

const render = (games, targetEl) => {
  games.forEach(game => {
    const {
      background_image,
      metacritic,
      name,
      platforms
    } = game;

    let gameEl = document.createElement('div');
    gameEl.classList.add('game');
    gameEl.innerHTML = `     
      <div class="image" style="background-image: url('${background_image}')"></div>
      <div class="game-info" >
          <div id="platforms" class="platforms">
            ${platforms.map(({ platform: { name } }) =>
              `<span class="platform">${name || ''}</span>`
            ).join('')}
          </div> 
          <h3>${name}</h3>
          <span class="rating ${getRatingClass(metacritic)}">${metacritic || 'N/A'}</span>
      </div>
    `;
    targetEl.appendChild(gameEl);
  });
};

const getRatingClass = vote => {
  if      (vote == null) return 'grey';
  else if (vote >= 80)   return 'green';
  else if (vote >= 50)   return 'orange';
  else                   return 'red';
}

main();
```

```css
.platforms {
  display: flex;
}

.platform {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.rating {
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.grey   { background: #AAA; }
.green  { background: #0F0; }
.orange { background: #F70; }
.red    { background: #F00; }

.game-info {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: thin solid grey;
}

.image {
  width: 178px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: @GaetanodeRoberto if it worked out for you, be sure to accept it.

Comment: I have to study ".map" and ".join", but roughly I think I understand